# Android - Save and update String sent from one activity to another

Tags: java, android

//I can send and receive two different values ​​in one **intent**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(checkBox.isChecked())
        {
            String trueThumb_check = "checked_thumb";
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("trueThumbnail", trueThumb_check);
            startActivity(i);
            killAc();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("falseThumbnail", "");
            startActivity(i);
            killAc();
        }

    }
```

//Then I received different values

```
try {
                Intent thumb_check = getIntent();
                String thumb_thumb = thumb_check.getStringExtra("trueThumbnail");
                if (thumb_thumb.contains("checked_thumb")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "checkBox ativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not checkBox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

//But I can not save the result. It needs to be saved and updated when the checkBox is checked or not

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("ch4an.ytheloader", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("trueThumbnail", thumb_thumb);
editor.commit();
```

**** EDIT: ****
For every time the user enters the **MainActivity** screen, the status that was sent from the preferences activity is saved.
That is, if he is saved, **Toast** will always appear.

Answer (score 0):

I Used Boolean Because it was fitting your problem better

Send From Activity

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("thumbnail",checkBox.isChecked());
                startActivity(i);
                killAc();
        }
```

Recieve from other

```
Boolean isChecked = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("thumbnail");
```

Then Save the isChecked

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();

prefs.edit().putBoolean("isChecked", isChecked).commit();
```